# Exclude page to be wrapped in gatsby wrapPageElement

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Here's the code in gatsby-ssr and gatsby-browser.

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => (
    <Store>
        <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
    </Store>
)
```

However I want to exclude some pages from being wrapped with Store and Layout, what is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: AFAIK I don't think it's possible to exclude pages. Also, for Provider components I believe you should use the [wrapRootElement](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been said, it's preferable to use `wrapRootElelement` instead of `wrapPageElement` for stores or other providers.

That said, you just can:

- You can create a new `Layout` component for those pages/components you don't want to wrap in `wrapRootElement`.
- Use the provided `props` (`location`, `data`, etc) to create a wrapping condition like:

  ```
  export const wrapRootElement = ({ element, props }) => {

      if(props.location.pathname.includes("page-with-wrap"){
       return <Store>
                <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
              </Store>
      }
  }
  ```